# RMProjectedRect to CGRcet

Tags: ios, mapbox

I want to draw bounding box shape for `RMProjectedRect` structs.
I need to convert `RMProjectedRect` to `CGRect` and and then create a shape and add it to superview.

[image]

does anyone know how to do this conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your hint.

Here is what I did:

```
CGRect frameRect = {[self.mapView projectedPointToPixel:gridMapRect.origin], [self.mapView projectedSizeToViewSize:gridMapRect.size]};
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the `RMMapView` routines under *Converting Map Coordinates* here:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/api/Classes/RMMapView.html

You can convert corners of the `RMProjectedRect`s into pixels coordinates for a given map viewport.